# iOS - call the method : [self.navigationController pushViewController: animated:], the screen get whole black

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, storyboard, pushviewcontroller

I want to push `SecViewController` by selecting a row in a tableview. I am using Storyboard to implement it. This is my code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

SecViewController *sec = [[SecViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:sec animated:NO];

}
```

And this is my storyboard:
[image]

But when I run this app:
it appears this situation:
[image: ViewController]
[image: SecViewController]

Why is it so?

Comment: You're creating a new instance of SecViewController but the code doesn't know what "nib" to use. Check out @Balaji's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your code as following :

```
SecViewController *sec = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"viewControllerIdentifier"];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:sec animated:NO];
```

Change **viewControllerIdentifier** as your storyboard identifier for that view controller ..

Hope it helps..

Comment: Yep! This is the way when using storyboard to design layout .If only use code for layout my way is also practicable.

Answer (score 0):

please check:

- your buttons must have constraints added, or size and origin setted properly
- your buttons are added in the correct superview
- if you have a view in that viewController :) (try to change the backgorund color ot be sure)